# How to pass down style into img tag from react semantic-ui Card component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

So, my end goal is to make 'Card' component appear to be rectangle, rather than rounded.

I'm looking for a way to pass a style down to img tag from react component(semantic-ui) "Card".
It seems like that the border radius of "Card"'s 'image' is non-zero. I like it to be zero, so it has the 90 degree angles. Note that I'm able to modify "Card" component's border-radius without a problem. What I want to know it to modify border-radius of the img inside of the "Card".

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'semantic-ui-react'

function PhotoList({ photos }) {
  const [displayPhotos, setDisplayPhotos] = React.useState(photos)

  async function handleClick(idx) {
    //some code...
  }

  function mapPhotosToItems(photos) {
    return photos.map((photo, idx) => ({
      // image: { src: photo.mediaUrl, style: 'border-radius:0' }, //tried.. doesn't work
      // image: { src: photo.mediaUrl, style: { borderRadius: 0 } }, //tried.. doesn't work
      image: { src: photo.mediaUrl },
      style: { borderRadius: 0 }, //this makes Card's corners rectangle.
      borderRadius: 0,
      childKey: photo._id,
      onClick: () => handleClick(idx)
    }))
  }

  return <Card.Group stackable itemsPerRow={10} centered items={mapPhotosToItems(displayPhotos)}/>;
}

export default PhotoList
```

On chrome inspect, I was able to modify border-radius of img on the fly (the yellow box is what I added in chrome debugger), so I can get the desired result. But how do I pass the style from my code?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the properties to the `image:` property, this is actually adding it to  the `<div>` that wraps around the `<img>`. This will be why the border radius is not changing on the image itself.

There is a property on the image called `rounded` and you can set this to false, which might be what you are looking for. `<Image src='https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png' size='medium' rounded={false} disabled />`

But I don't think that will work in your circumstance on a Card, so will have to do this with custom styling. You can add a `className` to the `image:` which will add it to the outer `<div>`, and then use custom CSS to style the image inside.

You will have to make the card have a border radius of 0 for it to be square as well.

**Example:**

```
image: { src: photo.mediaUrl, className: "square-img" }
```

**CSS**

```
.square-img > img {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.ui.card {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

You will need to import the CSS file at the top for the styles to come through.

`import './PhotoList.css';`

Created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-qrebq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark.

Comment: I should've said I also tried something similar to your suggestion. I also tried your suggestion exactly, unfortunately, it doesn't work. It does make, 
<div class="image square-img">, but img tag stays un-styled, therefore, still rounded. I appreciate your input though.

Comment: @Libertatem you will need to add the CSS for it to be styled.

Comment: Yea, I wish that was the case, but unfortunately, I have it in .css file. The problem seems like that the style isn't getting to the img tag.

Comment: Your edited answer did the trick! It looks like having '!important' makes the style effective. I need to read more about css. Thank you for your input/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple...

just import your module.css into the component and use it on your react semantic ui component:

```
import someCSS from './file.module.css';

return photos.map((photo, idx) => ({
    <Image src="..." className={someCss.classProperty} />
}))
```

or replace the image component with any other component that you want, if it has a classnames property it should work to pass your class properties like in above example...